# Omnet++: Run simulation in inet

Tags: omnet++, inet

I'm trying to run an examples in Inet ( this is wireless tutorial in inet homepage https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/tutorials/wireless/step1.html).
I have these lines in my NED file:

```
package inet.tutorials.wireless;

import inet.common.figures.DelegateSignalConfigurator;
import inet.netwoklayer.configurator.ipv4.IPv4NetworkConfigurator;
import inet.node.inet.INetworkNode;
import inet.physicallayer.contract.packetlevel.IRadioMedium;
import inet.visualizer.integrated.IntegratedCanvasVisualizer;
```

Then I run with command line

> opp_makemake
>
> make

but it has error with 'package inet.tutorials.wireless' line.

So what command line I should use? Or how should I rearrange the NED and omnetpp.ini source file in what folder?

Comment: Which directory are you running the command in? Also, do you have an explicit reason not to use the IDE?

Answer (score 0):

```
package inet.tutorials.wireless;
```

implies that you have to put your ned file in the folder inet/tutorials/wireless. If this is not the case, the mentioned error occurs.